# can't see properties of viewcontoller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I want to change the value of a label in my default view controller from a different class.

- So I start a simple 'Single View Application' iOS project (Xcode5)
- This automatically generates a ViewController for me (which I
  understand is the root view controller)
- I now add a label in my View and connect it to the ViewController (via IBOutlet mechanism)
- I call this outlet 'gameStateLabel', so it looks like this in the ViewController.h file

  ```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *gameStateLabel;
  ```

Next, I have a completely separate class which has the logic for my code, and based on a condition in the logic I want to change the UIlabel.

So I try to do this from my other class:

- Get an instance of the root view controller like this:

  ```
  UIViewController * uvc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
  ```

I think I now have an instance of the rootviewcontroller in uvc and should be able to reach in and change gameStateLabel.

BUT: I CANNOT do this uvc.gameStateLabel simply does not show up as a property even though it is clearly declared as a property and I've added the @synthesize for it also.

Any help will be greatly appreciated - I've been going nuts over this.

(For ref. I'm used to doing something similar on the Mac side where I'd declare a label as a property of the AppDelegate, get the instance of the Appdelegate and simply refer to the label property and change its text]

Here's the ViewController. Note that gameStateLable is a property

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *gameStateLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize gameStateLabel;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

And here is my class cls1 (which inherits from NSObject)

```
#import "cls1.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation cls1

-(void) dummy{

UIViewController * uvc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];

// uvc does NOT show gameStateLabel in intellisense, i.e. uvc.gameStateLabel does NOT work
```

}

Comment: try delegate functions.

Comment: Have you tried to print the rootViewController object you are obtaining by `[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController]`? What is the print in log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found two issues.

1. I had copied the code over from my Mac project and modified it. Something seems to have gone wrong.

I retyped the entire function and it solved most of the problem

1. uvc should be of the type ViewController* - not UIViewController* as I was doing

Thanks everyone for your replies - much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Add `#import "mainRootVC.h"` in you `CustomClass.m` file

And create object of **mainRootVC** such like,

```
mainRootVC *obj = [[mainRootVC alloc] init];
// Now you can access your label by
obj.gameStateLabel...
```

Comment: Yes, I have the import in place. #import "ViewController.h" in my case, but it doesn't help. I simply cannot see any declared properties of the view controller

Comment: check your connection with file's owner is proper ??? and also try to change @property (strong, nonatomic) instead of week.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

```
YourViewController *rootController =[(YourViewController*)[(YourAppDelegate*)
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this but no luck. I cannot even see the properties of the view controller - even if I create a completely new instance of it

Comment: Just posted code in main question above. Thanks for all the comments and help !

Answer (score 0):

Try the following too:

```
ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
```

It will return the initial view controller of the main storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

For sending information from a viewController to other viewController you have:

- Delegates:[Definiton and examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11)
- NSNotificationCenter:  [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

  NSString *label = @"label text";

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NAVIGATETO object:label userInfo:nil];

You can found tons of examples about those two. I recommend you use one of those.

Hope this helps a bit.